# Wordpress site broken home url two hosts, admin is with old host

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I've attempted to search first for related wordpress problems with urls breaking but couldn't find much regarding a wp site wpadmin being stuck on the old host too.

I have my company's WP site hosted at **webnames.ca**, migration was done some months ago and not by me. It has functioned fine so far, but the wp dashboard is still linked with bluehost.
The original dev site with a different domain is up and hosted on **bluehost**, still.

I attempted to make a change when trying to do a backup on bluehost before updating to WP 4.9, and inadvertently changed site addresses on bluehost.. [I should have backed up via webnames]

This affected the official current webnames.ca  address site, showing a ***Coming Soon* 'Bluehost'  splash page**, which should not be. I reset the url changes but it did not bring the site back.

If I suspend the webpage via the webnames.ca cpanel, the address shows 503 error[no mention of bluehost]. Im not sure what broke exactly with the URl or DNS.

Am I wrong to suspect the migration to new server wasn't fully complete? because for instance I  can still install wordpress app to the webnames server. Currently it has no apps or plugins installed. Could they have been duped forwarding to the old site?

I know as much that the wp-config.php file can be edited manually for the current site name, but would changes I made inadvertently on bluehost have affected the files on the new host?

I dont' currently have much php experience, so I am kind of lost.  I have tried to be clear in my description, let me know if I can clarify anything about the issue or improve my question.

Thanks so much.

Alex

Comment: Ah sorry I thought posted to correct area via searching first. Forgive my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DNS is, fine in my opinion, but you are missing an MX Record.

For me, http://www.patersoncomposites.ca/ loads perfectly, but I noticed webnames.ca is a Canadian server. I had to use a VPN to go to that site, due to it blocking me. That being said, the host may be the issue if you cannot see it load.

Also, your website is not WordPress. If you backed it as WP, something definitely went wrong. It seems the real website link is http://thepatersonco.com/ and then it connects to WP feature.

In final, the website works for me. This is some information I found that may be the issue, but way too much info for a quick fix answer.